# What method should i use to store text and pictures on the phone?

Tags: android, store

I am making an expense log application. The user can create a log by adding a picture of an object and then add the price and some comments to it.

I would like to know if I need to use database to store that data or i can store it directly to the phone.

Comment: You should not use a database for storing images, instead store only a link to the image on sdcard and load the image from the link only when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case a databse is the best fit. You could put all expenses in a String array in the SharedPreferences but this would be horrible to use. You would always need to load all expenses to memory if you are searching for one and so on. A database allows searching, filtering and ordering through SQL. It is a bigger initial amount to create the Database but the management of the data will be much nicer afterwards.

Demonick is right about the images, only store the path to the image file in the database and then retrieve the images from there. If you are storing images on the SD-Card the user or other apps can access and delete them so don't count on them to be available later.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can store data in Android application: SharedPreferences, files, SQLite databases, etc.  Which one you choose, depends on your requirements, amount of data you need to store, etc.  I suggest you read [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) section in the Android developer's guide to get started.